# max connections for t2.small aws RDS instances

Tags: amazon-rds

I need to know how many connections can be made with t2.small RDS instances, as i searched but getting different answers every where, in t2.micro instances we have 26 connections just need to know about t2.small too...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

t2.small can have maximum of 150 connections

see this link for more info please :

[max_connections at AWS RDS MySQL Instance Sizes](http://tritoneco.com/2015/11/23/max_connections-at-aws-rds-mysql-instance-sizes/)

Answer (score 0):

Actual info for Postgresql t3-instances (default.postgres10 parameter group):

- db.t3.micro  - 56 max_connections
- db.t3.small - 112 max_connections
- db.t3.medium - 225 max_connections
- db.t3.large  - 450 max_connections
- db.t3.xlarge - 901 max_connections
- db.t3.2xlarge - 1802 max_connections

Its similar for default.postgres9 and default.postgres11

Comment: Please don't post same  answer on multi-pal old post.